# JOLT Specification for converting filed value to field name

Tags: json, transactions, mapping, jolt

I am trying to convert the below JSON payload into a JSON that has the field name as the value of the field:

The jolt file that I have is working if field values are different. But if field values are the same then it is giving an array in the response.

Can you please help to provide jolt specifications for this?

Input JSON Payload:

```json
{
  "action": {
    "Success": true,
    "records": [
      {
        "Id": "Test_abc",
        "SubscriptionID": "ID_1"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Test_abc",
        "SubscriptionID": "ID_2"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Test_xyz",
        "SubscriptionID": "ID_3"
      }
    ],
    "type": "update"
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "action": {
    "Success": true,
    "records": {
      "Test_abc": {
        "SubscriptionID": "ID_1"
      },
      "Test_abc": {
        "SubscriptionID": "ID_2"
      },
      "Test_xyz": {
        "SubscriptionID": "ID_3"
      }
    },
    "type": "update"
  }
}
```

Solution not found yet.

Comment: Hi Tibco , welcome to SO. Are you sure about the duplicate `Id` values of `Test_abc`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&", // &1 replicates the literal "action"
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "S*": "&3.&2.@(1,Id).&" // &3 replicates the literal "action" (by going three level up the tree), &2 for "records", & replicates the current level attribute
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

presumingly converting one of the `Id` value from `Test_abc` to another one such as `Test_def`, since the desired output is wrong as a JSON value(There cannot be more than one object with the same tag at the same level)

Answer (score 0):

Your output is wrong. You can't have multiple objects with the same keys.

If You want to **support all objects** of `records` **array**, You should bring them into an array like this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "S*ID": "&3.&2[].@(1,Id).&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

But, if you want to have an object as your `records` in the output, You should **remove the duplicate `ID`** like this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "S*ID": "&3.&2.@(1,Id).&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "records": {
          "*": {
            "*": "ONE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]